# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'selectedItem' in null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have many micro-services which are implemented by different databases (mixed with SQL and no-SQL databases). Thus the tables have no physical relations between each other. But the ID's are stored within others when they need to be related. [Please do not ask me why the system is structured this way]
Everything is good till this point. Now I need to have a select component that I choose items from. Then I save the selected item's id in my tools table which is implemented in another database.

But because I store the ID of the item, the model sees only the id thus it makes me see the ID instead of its name. For that, I have made another get call to the database and I assigned the name of that id as the model of my select component. And I call setItem() function whenever the user selects another item which is as below:

```
setItem(val){
  this.selectedItem = `${val}`;
  querySearchItems(this.selectedItem); //this function simply searches the item.value and brings a list which are printed as options of the select.
}
```

My select component:

```
<el-form-item class="el-col-md-5" label="Item" prop="item">
    <el-select  v-model="this.selectedItem" filterable class="sm-column-width" @change="setItem"
        remote placeholder="Please enter a keyword" :remote-method="querySearchItems"
        :loading="loading">
        <el-option v-for="item in listItem" :key="item.value" :label="item.label" :value="item.value">
        </el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-form-item>
```

But whenever the user changes the value of the select box, it gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'selectedItem' in null", that I am guessing because the model I assigned to the select has nothing to do with the options I am getting from the database. Hence I need another work-around to display the name of the item and be able to change it. Thanks!

Note: I am using element-ui also, that's why the tags start with 'el'.

Comment: check the value of your `listItem`. Seems like it is null

Comment: it is not, I am able to choose items, whenever I click to choose it gives me that error :(

Comment: What function is throwing the error? Where is `selectedItem` being used with the `in` operator? What does that function look like?

Comment: @wing sorry for the error, I lost it because I solved it! (the rest of the error were just function names of its own, nothing of mine)Anyway I had no function which used 'selectedItem' with an 'in' operator anywhere. That's why it was odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding `value-key` attribute to my select component as follows:

```
 <el-select  v-model="selectedItem" value-key="selectedItem.value" filterable class="sm-column-width"
   remote placeholder="Please enter a keyword" :remote-method="querySearchItems"
   :loading="loading" @change="setItem">
           <el-option v-for="item in listItem" :key="item.value" :label="item.label" :value="item.value">
           </el-option>
 </el-select>
```

Also I have changed the declaration of my selectedItem (under data) as:

```
...
selectedItem: {label:'' , id: ''}
...
```

And when I queried, I assigned the value as follows:

```
  this.$http.get('localhost:8080/api/'+'items/' + id)
                  .then((response) => {
                  this.selectedItem = { label: response.body.itemName, value: response.body.id };
              });
```